# Cannot load json file using pandas read_json in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a json file I am trying to load into a pandas DataFrame whilst working in a notebook in jupyter lab. I'm using the following code for this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('goodreads_books_poetry.json', lines=True)
```

However the error I get is "ValueError: Expected object or value".
Weirdly, if I shove this into a python file and run it on the terminal it works just fine, and I would just use this method if it wasn't so slow and inconvenient for exploring data.
Here is a short snippet of the data

```
{"isbn": "", "text_reviews_count": "1", "series": [], "country_code": "US", "language_code": "eng", "popular_shelves": [{"count": "8", "name": "to-read"}, {"count": "3", "name": "poetry"}, {"count": "2", "name": "currently-reading"}, {"count": "1", "name": "01-kindle"}, {"count": "1", "name": "real-books"}, {"count": "1", "name": "personal-library"}], "asin": "", "is_ebook": "false", "average_rating": "3.83", "kindle_asin": "", "similar_books": [], "description": "Number 30 in a series of literary pamphlets published monthly and available at the price of 15 cents per copy, or a yearly subscription (19 numbers) for $1.25", "format": "Paperback", "link": "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16037549-vision-of-sir-launfal-and-other-poems", "authors": [{"author_id": "15585", "role": ""}], "publisher": "Houghton, Mifflin and Company", "num_pages": "80", "publication_day": "1", "isbn13": "", "publication_month": "11", "edition_information": "", "publication_year": "1887", "url": "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16037549-vision-of-sir-launfal-and-other-poems", "image_url": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1348176637m/16037549.jpg", "book_id": "16037549", "ratings_count": "3", "work_id": "5212748", "title": "Vision of Sir Launfal and Other Poems", "title_without_series": "Vision of Sir Launfal and Other Poems"}

{"isbn": "0811223981", "text_reviews_count": "2", "series": [], "country_code": "US", "language_code": "", "popular_shelves": [{"count": "100", "name": "to-read"}, {"count": "6", "name": "currently-reading"}, {"count": "3", "name": "drama"}, {"count": "3", "name": "plays"}, {"count": "2", "name": "books-i-own"}, {"count": "2", "name": "play"}, {"count": "2", "name": "read-2015"}, {"count": "1", "name": "golden"}, {"count": "1", "name": "poetry-and-plays"}, {"count": "1", "name": "retelling"}, {"count": "1", "name": "myth-fairy-tale"}, {"count": "1", "name": "fairytaleish"}, {"count": "1", "name": "favorites-2015"}, {"count": "1", "name": "2015-2016"}, {"count": "1", "name": "undated"}, {"count": "1", "name": "translated-fiction"}, {"count": "1", "name": "short-story-tbr"}, {"count": "1", "name": "jen-campbell-recs"}, {"count": "1", "name": "poetry"}, {"count": "1", "name": "theater"}, {"count": "1", "name": "to-buy"}, {"count": "1", "name": "maybe"}, {"count": "1", "name": "deutsch"}, {"count": "1", "name": "1910s"}, {"count": "1", "name": "to-read2"}, {"count": "1", "name": "new-directions"}, {"count": "1", "name": "tbp-dno"}, {"count": "1", "name": "fairytale-retellings"}, {"count": "1", "name": "published-2015"}, {"count": "1", "name": "translation"}, {"count": "1", "name": "fiction"}, {"count": "1", "name": "19th-early-20th"}, {"count": "1", "name": "german-language"}, {"count": "1", "name": "not-at-library"}, {"count": "1", "name": "flavorwire"}], "asin": "", "is_ebook": "false", "average_rating": "3.83", "kindle_asin": "B00U2WY9U8", "similar_books": [], "description": "Fairy Tales gathers the unconventional verse dramolettes of the Swiss writer Robert Walser. Narrated in Walser's inimitable, playful language, these theatrical pieces overturn traditional notions of the fairy tale, transforming the Brothers Grimm into metatheater, even metareflections.\nSnow White forgives the evil queen for trying to kill her, Cinderella doubts her prince and enjoys being hated by her evil stepsisters; the Fairy Tale itself is a character who encourages her to stay within the confines of the story. Sleeping Beauty, the royal family, and its retainers are not happy about being woken from their sleep by an absurd, unpretentious, Walser-like hero. Mary and Joseph are taken aback by what lies in store for their baby Jesus.", "format": "Paperback", "link": "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22466716-fairy-tales", "authors": [{"author_id": "16073", "role": ""}, {"author_id": "3484503", "role": "Translator"}, {"author_id": "367928", "role": "Translator"}, {"author_id": "1028358", "role": "Preface"}], "publisher": "New Directions", "num_pages": "128", "publication_day": "20", "isbn13": "9780811223980", "publication_month": "4", "edition_information": "", "publication_year": "2015", "url": "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22466716-fairy-tales", "image_url": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1404958407m/22466716.jpg", "book_id": "22466716", "ratings_count": "37", "work_id": "41905435", "title": "Fairy Tales: Dramolettes", "title_without_series": "Fairy Tales: Dramolettes"}
```

I'm actually using the same code from here: https://towardsdatascience.com/recommendation-system-in-python-lightfm-61c85010ce17, as I'm trying to use their article and dataset to play around with to explore the lightfm model, so I don't understand what's going wrong.
I also played around a little with the orient parameter, but didn't have any success from this.

Comment: can you try `pd.json_normalize('goodreads_books_poetry.json')`  ? does that work.

Comment: Are your python and json files in the same folder?

Comment: @Umar.H thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that gives "NotImplementedError"

Comment: @R.Marolahy yes they are

Comment: @Chloe can you update your pandas version? I can't read your json file in fine using the above method

Comment: Then try to use the full path of the json file.

Comment: @Umar.H I've just updated to the latest pandas version, still same errors sadly

Comment: @R.Marolahy full path name gives the same error

Comment: Which OS are you using? on Windows sometimes you have to add \\\  or  r' '.

Comment: @R.Marolahy I am on macOS

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but can you give the folder structure on where you create the notebook? Bcs there are two possible causes:

1. Wrong filename/path
2. Malformed json file (unlikely in your case, if you download from the source written in the article you mentioned)